# Rendering issue got flash like artifacts on final render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I am getting light flashes on my final render i am rendring with cycles can anyone help me with this issue?
Following are the images of the issue

[image: Render with flash Bad render]

[image: Render without flash good render]

[image: Render Settings]